# From Cloud Code, how can I query for Installations matching a set of Users?

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm using a standalone Parse server, trying to send a push notification to multiple Installations.

Parse Server won't let me query the Installation collection from Cloud Code, returning the following error:

```
Error handling request: ParseError {
  code: 119,
  message: 'Clients aren\'t allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.' } code=119, message=Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.
```

The query in Cloud Code looks like this:

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.containedIn('user', users);
pushQuery.find({ ...
```

What's the proper way to get a list of Installations for a set of Users and send pushes to all of them?

I've also tried to get Cloud Code to use the masterKey by calling `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` immediately before the query. No effect and the master key is not included in the query request headers.

Comment: The error mentions clients aren't allowed to use the find query. How are you calling the cloud function from the client?

Comment: This is all in a Parse.Cloud.afterSave() callback. The client calls the server to update an object, and I'm trying to run this query after the save. The query is not run by the client directly.

Comment: weird that you are getting the client error then. Could you put the query somewhere other than the callback ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` is deprecated since Parse-server version 2.3.0. You now need to make use of `useMasterKey: true` in your query.

Eg:

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.containedIn('user', users);
pushQuery.find({useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) {
```